# VB.NET Exception when running System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.Create (ECCurve curve)

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

I am getting an exception when I use the `System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1` property of Framework 4.7.
The exception I am getting is (stackoverflow):

> The specified 'brainpoolP256r1' curve or its parameters are not valid
>   for this platform. Stackoverflow:
>
> in System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Create (ECCurve curve, Func`2
>   algorithihmResolver)
>  in
>   System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsaCng.GenerateKey (ECCurve curve) in System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.Create (ECCurve curve)

In local machines that I have in the office it works for me in all, but in the different servers that I have tried, it has not worked in any.

```
    Dim pubKeyX As Byte() = _Key.Skip(1).Take(32).ToArray()
    Dim pubKeyY As Byte() = _Key.Skip(33).ToArray()
    Dim params As New ECParameters() With
        {
            .Q = New ECPoint With
            {
                .X = pubKeyX,
                .Y = pubKeyY
            },
            .Curve = _ECCurve
        }
    Dim oRes As ECDsa = ECDsa.Create(_ECCurve)
```

This last line is the one that causes the exception

Comment: Please format your codes and errors.

Comment: I have already formatted it.

Comment: No, your code was edited for you but you changed it back to UNformated.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to do it.